# How to pull data from XML and then extract the data

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm very new to Android development and Java. This is probably a simple answer but I cant seem to find the info anywhere. I know I can pull data from my XML by using:

```
Double.parseDouble(example.getText().toString());
```

but what I need to to is then extract the data and add it together.

Example: I pull the data and its `1234` then I need to add `1+2+3+4`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your data is the string `1234` and that represents `1+2+3+4`? Why is that?

Comment: Please include an example of XML file that you are trying to parse - if I remember correctly, `getText()` ignores markup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want to add all the digits in a string then you would do this:

(pseudocode)

length = number of characters in string

runningtotal = 0;

loop through all charcaters in string, 0 to length-1

extract character at each loop position

runningtotal += Integer.getString(character);

But I suspect this is not actually what you're trying to do. More info?